# How to name javascript files

Tags: javascript

I was asked to add some new javascript logics to a project call 'Mist' a few days ago.

I add a folder named 'Framework' and a other named 'PageScripts'.

Here is what I am thinking : 
Framework scripts of our procject(which we have none right now.) should placed in 'Framework'.
Scripts only related to specific pages should be placed in folder 'PageScripts'.

But my manager has some disagreements with me on naming js files.

I add file name 'Mist.configs.js' to folder 'Framework' 
a file named 'filemanage.html.js' to folder 'PageScripts'.

I create an object called Mist with a property called 'configs'. in Mist.configs.js.
And filemanage.html.js contains only scripts related to page 'filemanage.html'.

Opinions of my manager:
'Mist.configs.js' should be named 'config.js' because our project is already call 'Mist'.
'filemanage.html.js' should be named 'filemanage.js' and its no need to add '.html' in it because it is already in 'PageScripts' folder.

Opinions of mine:
'Mist' should be keeped because it is a namespace. It is more readable.
'
'.html' should be keeped because it is related to 'filemanage.html' what if we have a page name filemanage.php? and other util file 'filemanage.js'?

What do you think? Any suggetions on naming and structuring js files ?

I don't know how to convince my manager and he ask me fine some documents to support my opinions.

What should I do ?

Thanks.

Comment: This is not really the place to ask this type of question. Some advice though, just do what your manager wants.

Comment: just do what your manager wants

Comment: The best thing to is not simply do what your manager wants, but understand why they want it that way.  Honestly though, things like this come down to being consistent, either within this project or within other projects your team is maintaining.  Also, from what little I can tell about your project, I would agree with your manager.

Comment: Does the project already have any naming conventions? If so, follow that (or migrate EVERYTHING if the new system is so quantifiably better to justify the effort + possible breakage + retraining).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's no need to recount the back-and-forth with your manager so extensively. That said, it seems to come down to a few core questions, which I'll address here.

### Contributing to a happy dev team

Regardless of the points after this, you **always** want to prioritize keeping the project consistent and your team happy. If your team is using a certain methodology, keep it unless you are willing and allowed to change the system for the entire project. Second, tend towards standard practices for your platform because that makes it easier for every other developer to understand what you've done, hence it lowers costs and reduces development time for the company.

### Organizing Javascript

Most of the time, Javascript should be put in one (possibly nested) folder and optimized in accordance with your platform. That is, set it up so that it can use a CDN if appropriate, or an asset pipeline if in Rails, and so on. It's going to be very confusing for future developers if javascript files are almost arbitrarily placed in various folders, because one can almost guarantee they will not interpret every location decision the same way as you did.

### File extensions

Deciding whether to name a file `filemanage.html.js` vs `filemanage.js` should depend on whether you are putting HTML inside the file or not. It should not be used simply to indicate that it's somehow 'relevant' to some HTML file.